# incomprehension when installing airflow locally

Tags: airflow

I want to deploy Airflow localy in order to run a pipeline that will retrieve csv file on Google Cloud Storage and process some operation on it.

So I started to install airflow. Howeover there are many way to do it.

First I saw in a site that we need to have a kubernetes cluster if we want to install Airflow.

But in another site https://blog.knoldus.com/apache-airflow-installation-guide-and-basic-commands/#installation-of-airflow I saw I can install Airflow following this command :

```
virtualenv apache_airflow

cd apache_airflow/bin
source activate

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

pip install apache-airflow

airflow db init

airflow webserver -p 8081
```

So I have some questions :

1. In last site we don't have kubernetes cluster. Why it's not necessary here ?
2. Why we execute the command `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` ?
   When I do

   `cd ~/`

   `ls (or ls -a)`

I don't see any airflow file.

Someone can explain me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, just like you said, there are a lot of ways to install airflow.

Kubernetes is a container orchestration system and it can be used with airflow. However this is not a necessity.

From the [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#constraints-files)

> Airflow installation can be tricky sometimes because Airflow is both a library and an application. Libraries usually keep their dependencies open and applications usually pin them, but we should do neither and both at the same time. We decided to keep our dependencies as open as possible (in setup.cfg and setup.py) so users can install different version of libraries if needed. This means that from time to time plain pip install apache-airflow will not work or will produce an unusable Airflow installation.

> In order to have a repeatable installation, we also keep a set of “known-to-be-working” constraint files in the constraints-main, constraints-2-0, constraints-2-1 etc. orphan branches and then we create a tag for each released version e.g. constraints-2.5.0. This way, we keep a tested and working set of dependencies.

You can read more about how you can install airflow and be sure that it'll work (for the Python version you use aswell) [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#constraints-files).

2. Secondly, about `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`

When you install airflow, it needs a directory to live in. If you are on a Linux system, your DAG files are in '/home/YOUR_USERNAME/airflow/dags' by default.

If you look at the default config (the airflow.cfg file that you'll encounter after your installation), you'll see that airflow expects the DAG scripts in `dags_folder = /home/YOUR_USERNAME/airflow/dags`

When you open up a terminal and type `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`, you are basically saying that "Hey this is where my Airflow is and I'll build things inside this folder"

Personally, I'd recommend [this site](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#modules-management) to learn more about the directory structure.